# How do I speed up a piece of python code which has a numpy function embedded in it?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython, numba

Here is the rate limiting function in my code

```
def timepropagate(wv1, ham11,
                  ham12, ham22, scalararray, nt):
    wv2 = np.zeros((nx, ny), 'c16')
    fw1 = np.zeros((nx, ny), 'c16')
    fw2 = np.zeros((nx, ny), 'c16')
    for t in range(0, nt, 1):
        wv1, wv2 = scalararray*wv1, scalararray*wv2
        fw1, fw2 = (np.fft.fft2(wv1), np.fft.fft2(wv2))
        fw1 = ham11*fw1+ham12*fw2
        fw2 = ham12*fw1+ham22*fw2
        wv1, wv2 = (np.fft.ifft2(fw1), np.fft.ifft2(fw2))
        wv1, wv2 = scalararray*wv1, scalararray*wv2
    del(fw1)
    del(fw2)
    return np.array([wv1, wv2])
```

What I would need to do is find a reasonably fast implementation that would allow me to go at twice the speed, preferably the fastest.

The more general question I'm interested in, is what way can I speed up this piece, using minimal possible connections back to python. I assume that even if I speed up specific segments of the code, say the scalar array multiplications, I would still come back and go from python at the Fourier transforms which would take time. Are there any ways I can use, say numba or cython and not make this "coming back" to python in the middle of the loops?
On a personal note, I'd prefer something fast on a single thread considering that I'd be using my other threads already.

Edit: here are results of profiling, the 1st one for 4096x4096 arrays for 10 time steps, I need to scale it up for nt = 8000.

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.099    0.099  432.556  432.556 <string>:1(<module>)
   40    0.031    0.001   28.792    0.720 fftpack.py:100(fft)
   40   45.867    1.147   68.055    1.701 fftpack.py:195(ifft)
   80    0.236    0.003   47.647    0.596 fftpack.py:46(_raw_fft)
   40    0.102    0.003    1.260    0.032 fftpack.py:598(_cook_nd_args)
   40    1.615    0.040   99.774    2.494 fftpack.py:617(_raw_fftnd)
   20    0.225    0.011   29.739    1.487 fftpack.py:819(fft2)
   20    2.252    0.113   72.512    3.626 fftpack.py:908(ifft2)
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fftpack.py:93(_unitary)
   40    0.631    0.016    0.820    0.021 fromnumeric.py:43(_wrapit)
   80    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 fromnumeric.py:457(swapaxes)
   40    0.338    0.008    1.158    0.029 fromnumeric.py:56(take)
  200    0.064    0.000    0.219    0.001 numeric.py:414(asarray)
    1  329.728  329.728  432.458  432.458 profiling.py:86(timepropagate)
    1    0.036    0.036  432.592  432.592 {built-in method builtins.exec}
   40    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
  120    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
  241    3.930    0.016    3.930    0.016 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
   40   18.861    0.472   18.861    0.472 {built-in method numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.cfftb}
   40   28.539    0.713   28.539    0.713 {built-in method numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.cfftf}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.fft.fftpack_lite.cffti}
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
   40    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
   40    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reverse' of 'list' objects}
   80    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'setdefault' of 'dict' objects}
   80    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'swapaxes' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
   40    0.022    0.001    0.022    0.001 {method 'take' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

I think I've done it wrong the first time, using time.time() to calculate time differences for small arrays and extrapolating the conclusions for larger ones.

Comment: The first rule of optimizing is to profile the function. Which part is the bottleneck? If it's the fft you probably cannot expect any significant speedups.

Comment: What is `hamij` in this case? Would it be possible to make use of the convolution theorem and perform the operations in the time domain instead of the frequency domain? As the above commenter said, I don't think you can make an fft much faster than it already is.

Comment: You'll want to look at the `fft` package, but I think, after one or python calls it ends up using a compiled library.

Comment: @MSeifert the fft is the bottleneck, but the  I'm aiming to make this implementation around twice as fast

Comment: @MSeifert the fft is the bottleneck, but the hamiltonian multiplication, but the part between the fft and ifft takes around 3/4th the time

I'm aiming to make this implementation around twice as fast, not orders of magnitude, considering that I might take 2-3 days to get results for a particular system. I haven't tried other ffts, but would they compete with an mkl numpy fft?


sorry I accidentally pressed enter

Comment: Can you please give a complete example of running the function with appropriately sized input arrays and necessary globals?

Comment: You might get some benefit to doing to multiplications "inplace" - e.g. `fw1 = ham11*fw1+ham12*fw2` -> `fw1 *= ham11; fw1 += (ham12*fw2)`. But this likely depends on the array sizes

Comment: @PraharshSuryadevara Could you [edit] the question and include the arrays (what JoshAdel said) and the result of the profiling?

Comment: As eigenchris suggests, if `hamij` are small, convolution might be faster than using an FFT. See [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/ReviewFourier/FFT_Convolution_vs_Direct.html) for instance. The numbers will change if your arrays are of different sizes, but you can do the calculation yourself to see whether or not it's worth it. Better yet, try both and profile!

Comment: @JoshAdel here is I've updated my question. I've also uploaded the code piece I intend to run here, https://github.com/spraharsh/Masters-Project/blob/master/graphprop.py for what the input arrays actually are, considering they're a bit large to put here

Comment: @MSeifert I've properly profiled my function now, It does look like the bottleneck is the fft itself :(

Comment: @Praveen hamij are 4096x4096. I'd come from the convolution to the FFT method for the speedup . Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If most of the time is spent in the hamiltonian multiplication, you may want to apply numba on that part. The most benefit coming from removing all the temporal arrays that would be needed if evaluating expressions from within NumPy.

Bear also in mind that the arrays (4096, 4096, c16) are big enough to not fit comfortably in the processor caches. A single matrix would take 256 MiB. So think that the performance is unlikely to be related at all with the operations, but rather on the bandwidth. So implement those operations in a way that you only perform one pass in the input operands. This is really trivial to implement in *numba*. Note: You will only need to implement in *numba* the hamiltonian expressions.

I want also to point out that the "preallocations" using np.zeros seems to signal that your code is not following your intent as:

```
    fw1 = ham11*fw1+ham12*fw2
    fw2 = ham12*fw1+ham22*fw2
```

will actually create new arrays for fw1, fw2. If your intent was to reuse the buffer, you may want to use "fw1[:,:] = ...". Otherwise the np.zeros do nothing but waste time and memory.

You may want to consider to join (wv1, wv2) into a (2, 4096, 4096, c16) array. The same with (fw1, fw2). That way code will be simpler as you can rely on broadcasting to handle the "scalararray" product. fft2 and ifft2 will actually do the right thing (AFAIK).